# quasi-finite group schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, modular-forms

The following is what Mazur wrote on page 91 of his paper, Modular curves and the Eisenstein ideal, published in Publ. IHES in 1977, [DOI: 10.1007/BF02684339](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02684339) (freely available at [eudml](https://eudml.org/doc/103950)):

Let $m$ be an integer. Let $J[m]_{/\mathbb{Z}}$ denote the scheme-theoretic kernel of multiplication by $m$ in the Neron model of $J_{/\mathbb{Z}}$. **Since $J$ is semi-stable, $J[m]_{/\mathbb{Z}}$ is a quasi-finite flat group scheme**, whose restriction to $S'=\text{Spec} \mathbb{Z}[1/N]$ is finite and flat.

Here, $J=J_0(N)$ with $N$ prime.

I have two questions:

1. It seems that his claim is still true when $N$ is squarefree because $J$ is still semi-stable. But I don't know why. Can someone explain this?
2. Suppose that $N$ is not squarefree, so $J$ does not have semistable reduction at a prime whose square divides $N$. Is the same statement true if $\text{gcd}(m, N)$ is squarefree? If not, is it true that if we assume that $\text{gcd}(m, N)=1$?

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks for providing a link where you can get for an expensive price a scan of a 1977 paper, which you can get freely (and legally) here http://www.numdam.org/issues/PMIHES_1977__47_

Comment: @YCor In fact, if you look at my edit, you can see that I have included both doi (with link) and eudml link (Which is free and links to the same copy as your comment. I have even explicitly mentioned this [in the edit summary](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/286796/revisions).) Of course, you are by far more experienced MO user than me, feel free to make further improvements to the post, if needed.

Comment: Oh, indeed. The problem seems to be that the DOI points to the paying site.

Comment: @YCor I understand that. Still, some users might have a subscription, so they can get (possibly) a better copy from the doi-link. I considered adding only eudml, but I opted to add also doi, since [doi link should be stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier). Of course, if you think including only eudml link or some other link is preferrable, feel free to edit the post. Here is a link to somewhat related discussion on meta: [edits with links to material under restricted access](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3193).